# OutOfRangeError : FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 32, cu rrent size 0)

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing

I have a terrible error in my tensorflow program..

i have 1028 image dataset.

I saved the name and label of the image file in a text file.

It then reads the image file names from file_Q ().
Then use tf.train.slice_input_producer () to create the queue (is it correct to create a queue?).
The name of the queue is input_queue.

It takes input_queue from read_data () and makes it into image using decode_jpeg.
Then return.

Read_data_batch () accepts the returned image and label.
Try tf.reshape () and tf.train.batch () to do 32 batches.

The path to process it is as follows.

```
Def file_Q (fileaddr):
 Train_labels = []
 Train_images = []

 For line in open (fileaddr, 'r'):
  Cols = re.split (',', line)
  Train_images.append (cols [0])
  Train_labels.append (int (cols [1]))

 Input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer ([train_images, train_labels], num_epochs = None, shuffle = True)

 Return input_queue # return [addr text, label] queue


Def read_data (input_queue):

 Image_addr = input_queue [0]
 Label = input_queue [1]
 Image = tf.image.decode_jpeg (tf.read_file (image_addr), channels = 3) # create 3-d rgb image object using image addr
 Print 'image_addr:', image_addr
 Print 'label:', label
 Print 'image:', image
 Return image, label, image_addr

Def read_data_batch (FILE_ADDR_):
 Input_queue = file_Q (FILE_ADDR_)
 Image, label, filename = read_data (input_queue)
 Image = tf.reshape (image, [1344, 200, 3])
 Batch_image, batch_label = tf.train.batch ([image, label], batch_size = 32) #, capacity = 20000, min_after_dequeue = 100)
 Return batch_image, batch_label

Bat_im, bat_la = read_data_batch (FILE_ADDR)

With tf.Session () as sess:
 Sess.run (tf.local_variables_initializer ())
 Sess.run (tf.global_variables_initializer ())
 Coord = tf.train.Coordinator ()
 Threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners (coord = coord, sess = sess)

 For i in range (10):
  Batch_im_, batch_la_ = sess.run ([bat_im, bat_la])
  Print batch_im_, batch_la_

 Coord.request_stop ()
 Coord.join (threads)
 Print ('finish')
```

Error message is like below..

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 32, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

i dont know why queue is dead before dequeue.
I would really appreciate it if you could tell us your opinion or solution.
I want to hear your valuable opinions.

Thank you for reading.